# bash - for loop different iterations

Tags: bash, shell, for-loop

I know how to do sequential for loops like:

```
for i in $(seq 0 63)
do
  echo $i
done
```

This would print 0-63 .
But what if I wanted certain numbers looped like only 0, 5, 25, 43, 44, 51, 54.

I know I could do the following:

```
for i in $(seq 0 63)
do
  if [ "$i" -eq 0 ] || [ "$i" -eq 5 ] || [ "$i" -eq 25 ] || [ "$i" -eq 43 ] || [ "$i" -eq 44 ] || [ "$i" -eq 51 ] || [ "$i" -eq 54 ]; then
    echo $i
  fi
done
```

But the result will be that it still goes through those loop iterations, and is not an efficient solution.

Is there something I can use with seq to describe these certain numbers 0,5,25,43,44,51,54?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to iterate over a known list, you can simply store the elements, space-separated, in a variable and loop over that:

```
nums="0 5 25 43 44 51 54";
for i in $nums;
do echo $i;
done;
```

Comment: For the OP, `seq` is just generating such a hard-coded list.